# Correct OpenGL version on a notebook with two AMD GPUs

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, gentoo

I'm using Gentoo on a notebook with two AMD GPUs: an integrated and a discrete card. Here's what `lspci` is returning:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8650G] [1002:990b]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Richland [Radeon HD 8650G] [1462:10ef]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Neptune XT [Radeon HD 8970M] [1002:6801] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

What is the correct way to setup the open source driver now? According to the [feature support table on Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Radeon#Feature_support), I set in `make.conf`:

```
VIDEO_CARDS="radeon r600 radeonsi"
```

so both drivers are present to support both GPUs. What bothers me is the `glxinfo` output:

```
$ DRI_PRIME=0 glxinfo | grep -i opengl # integrated gpu
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.3.7
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30

$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep -i opengl # discrete gpu
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD PITCAIRN
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.3.7
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

Again, according to the feature table from above, the drivers for both GPUs support at least OpenGL 3.3 which is obviously not the case here. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, after struggling, trying and lurking for a week or so, some guy from a russian linux community helped me out, so I'll repost it here. The reason was the enabled `bindist` use flag for mesa package:

```
~ $ equery uses mesa
[ Legend : U - final flag setting for installation]
[        : I - package is installed with flag     ]
[ Colors : set, unset                             ]
 * Found these USE flags for media-libs/mesa-11.0.0_rc2:
 U I
 + + abi_x86_32           : 32-bit (x86) libraries
 + + bindist              : Disable patent-encumbered ARB_texture_float, EXT_texture_shared_exponent, and EXT_packed_float extensions.
 + + classic              : Build drivers based on the classic architecture.
...
```

Even better, I had the `bindist` use flag enabled globally. After removing it from `make.conf`, I also disabled the `classic` use flag for `media-libs/mesa` in `package.use` and remerged mesa:

```
~ $ DRI_PRIME=0 glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.7.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.0.0-rc2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.0-rc2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.0.0-rc2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00

~ $ DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep -i opengl                                                                                                                         
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD PITCAIRN (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.7.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.0.0-rc2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.10
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.0-rc2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.0.0-rc2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```